# Merge values from cells when criteria a met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I am working on a file where in column A I have got values like:

```
HUAN-A5
HUAN-A5-Cream
BO-2-9077
BO-2-9077-Camel-Length - 70cm
BO-2-9077-White -Length - 70cm
RESE-A5
RESE-A5-Blue-85cm
RESE-A5-Blue-90cm
RESE-A5-Blue-95cm
ZANA-A5
ZANA-A5-Grey-80cm
ZANA-A5-Grey-85cm
ZANA-A5-Grey-90cm
ZANA-A5-Grey-95cm
```

First code without any parameters is a parent product, products below are child products, I need to create a new field for parent so first code without any parameters, where I will pickup sizes etc. from child products. So in this specific example:

```
ZANA-A5
ZANA-A5-Grey-80cm
ZANA-A5-Grey-85cm
ZANA-A5-Grey-90cm
ZANA-A5-Grey-95cm
```

In row where I have got ZANA-A5, I will create a new column, e.g. sizes and these will be 80 | 85 | 90 | 95

Please note that I dont need to extract sizes from the column A as I have got these stored in different column, one size per variant.

Here is an example spreadsheet I am working on
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16yrv1vaarIqi7sWGfZNYxFNUtR30MiTruP9zqJk8Ql8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ehm To be clear. Test, Test1, Test2, Test3 would be written in Column 1 and Exp, Exp1, Exp2, Exp3 would be written in Column 2 because the needed code would detect this?

Comment: look up regex. that will do the job for you.

Comment: Column A could be Test, Test1, Test2, Test3 then Column B would have  Exp, Exp1, Exp2, Exp3. What I want to achieve is, in the row where Test is, I want to create a field that would check for all occurrences of TestX, and if there is an occurrence it will then merge values from Column B into this new field.

Comment: Andreas is right, you should put some effort in your Code. But as a hint. Lookup the "If - condition", the "Instr- condition" and the "Do - Loop" your might work with 2 loops. One for counting through your column and one for writing.
Good luck

Comment: I've read through this 3 times and I still am not at all understanding what you want. Can you please post, for your sample data `Zana-whatever` rows, what the output/end-product would look like? I'm not getting what this means: `I will create a new column, e.g. sizes and these will be 80 | 85 | 90 | 95` A new column from 5 rows that has only 4 values. What happens to `gray` should `color` not also be a column beside `size`?

Comment: If we are going through parsing these product names for `size` but then we hit `HUAN-A5-Cream` where there is no size... how do we know that isn't a size (I mean... I know "cream" isn't a size because I'm a human, but how do we tell the computer that `cream` isn't a size).Or are these products ALWAYS `<sku>-<color>-<size>` format? If that's the case, that the sku of the subproduct always is in the same format, then would you want a column for size?

Comment: I think this would be pretty simple to write up, but I would want two things: 1: Confirm that a sku's format is always `<sku>-<color>-<size>` and 2: provide what the output would look like (perhaps for your original list with all of those skus).

Comment: Here is an example spreadsheet I am working on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16yrv1vaarIqi7sWGfZNYxFNUtR30MiTruP9zqJk8Ql8/edit?usp=sharing